# .net 5 - Signalr - Messagepack - lz4 - Error: unable to find ext type 98

Tags: angular, signalr, msgpack, .net-5, lz4

Got this error un .net core 5 solution with angular client after enabling lz4BlockArray compression.
Without compression everithing seems to work pretty fine.
Looking around for motivation but i found nothing.
Seems like some decoders aren't loaded correctly.

That's client side error, no server side error

```
Utils.js:208 [2020-12-01T09:01:42.527Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) data received. Binary data of length 1086.
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: unable to find ext type 98
    at decodeExt (decoder.js:432)
    at tryDecode (decoder.js:266)
    at decodeArray (decoder.js:338)
    at tryDecode (decoder.js:288)
    at decodeArray (decoder.js:338)
    at tryDecode (decoder.js:288)
    at decodeArray (decoder.js:338)
    at tryDecode (decoder.js:288)
    at Object.decode (decoder.js:103)
    at MessagePackHubProtocol.push.jxpC.MessagePackHubProtocol.parseMessage (MessagePackHubProtocol.js:79)
```

#### To Reproduce

My configuration:

Partial project

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Development;DStaging;DProduction;Staging;Production</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlSanitizer" Version="5.0.355" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch" Version="7.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Startup.cs

```
  var resolver = CompositeResolver.Create(
               DynamicEnumAsStringResolver.Instance,
               StandardResolver.Instance
           );
           services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol(

               option =>
               {
                   option.SerializerOptions =
                       MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(resolver)
                           .WithCompression(MessagePackCompression.Lz4BlockArray)
                           .WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.UntrustedData);
               });
```

package.json

```
"@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.0",
"@microsoft/signalr-protocol-msgpack": "^5.0.0",
```

Connection

```
const builder = new HubConnectionBuilder();
      // as per setup in the startup.cs
      this._hubConnection = builder.withUrl('url', {
        accessTokenFactory:
          () => {
            const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            return JSON.parse(token).access_token;
          },
      }).configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace).withAutomaticReconnect(new SignalrRetryPolicy()).withHubProtocol(new MessagePackHubProtocol()).build();
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [.NET MessagePack libraries README](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp/blob/master/README.md)

> MessagePackCompression has two modes, Lz4Block and Lz4BlockArray. Neither is a simple binary LZ4 compression, but a special compression integrated into the serialization pipeline, using MessagePack ext code (Lz4BlockArray (98) or Lz4Block (99)). Therefore, it is not readily compatible with compression offered in other languages.

The important part is the last sentence, other languages might not be compatible. And in this case the Angular client is using a MessagePack library that doesn't support these ext codes for compression.

Comment: Seems like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr-protocol-msgpack depends on https://www.npmjs.com/package/msgpack5 version 4.0.2  ( https://github.com/mcollina/msgpack5 ) which is a two-years old last release package. Mcollina never talk about lz4 in his github.  I'll wait for other response then i'll tag yours the right one

Comment: msgpack + lz4 is appearing oncly in C# client / server https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/1281238090871271425
from github source lz4 nor lzblock is never referenced 
maybe we can ask the request !